# @RequestBody list is never empty, just null

Tags: java, spring, rest

my task is to check whether the list in Response Body is empty or not. If it's empty I throw exception, if it's not, I continue working with it. The problem is that the GET request is done by POST request, because of search limits etc.

Here is the method:

```
@PostMapping("/fees")
public List<FeeSetupDTO> getFeeSetups(@RequestBody List<FeeRequest> request
) {
    if (!request.isEmpty()) {  //request size = 1
        try {
            return ...;
        } catch (NotImplementedException e) {
            ...;
        }
    } else {
        throw new PublicException(PMT_NOT_FOUND); //Never thrown because list is never empty
    }
}
```

The Request body in my request looks like this:

```
[{ }] //Empty list
```

The problem is that the list that I get is never empty, its size is 1 and it's just null, but still it counts as an element in list. Every FeeRequest consists from these objects:

```
feeName = null;
feeCode = null;
feeAmount = null;
```

Do you have any ideas how could I check if the list from Request Body is empty?

Comment: You can validate the `List` with `@Valid` annotation, like this `@alid @RequestBody List<FeeRequest> request`, it will be automaticallly validated by Spring.

Comment: @cнŝdk But if I'am getting it correctly it still won't throw the exception stating that the list is empty.

Comment: please show request

Comment: @ekiryuhin what do you mean? The request looks something like this: `POST {url}/fees` and the Request Body as I mentioned above is just an empty list: `[{ }]`

Comment: @Martin You can always configure a Validator to throw the desired Exception, check [**Configuring a Validator for use by Spring MVC**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch05s07.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An empty `list` is like this `[]`.

The list `[{ }]` you are sending, is not empty, you sent a `list` with an empty `object`.

Comment: Oh, now I feel really stupid, so I did everything correctly, just the request was bad, thanks...